# How can I turn Stream into RepeatedField in Rust?

Tags: stream, rust, protocol-buffers

I've got the following struct in Rust that I want to return from my service:

```
#[derive(PartialEq,Clone,Default)]
pub struct Response {
    pub names: ::protobuf::RepeatedField<String>,
}
```

and I set its `names` field (see [the doc](https://docs.rs/protobuf/2.0.2/protobuf/struct.RepeatedField.html) about its type) in the following way:

```
use protobuf::{Message, RepeatedField};
use futures::future::Future;
use futures::Stream;

fn create_response(names: impl Stream<Item = String, Error = CustomError>) -> Result<Response, CustomError>
   let names = names.collect().wait()?;
   let mut response = Response::new();
   response.set_names(RepeatedField::from_vec(names));
   Ok(response)
}
```

Now I want to optimise this piece of code and avoid blocking `collect` operation. Is there any way to stream that `names` directly into `response.names` field (i.e., avoid the step of creating a `names` vector)?

Comment: There is something wrong with this code. You are using `?` but the function doesn't return a `Result`.

Comment: It's very difficult to answer the question: "how to change behaviour X to behaviour Y?", when the code for X doesn't even work.

Comment: Also what is Stream ? Where it comes from ?

Comment: @ÖmerErden One would have to _guess_ it's from `futures`, and then guess again that it's the latest version `0.1.25`...

Comment: @E4_net_or_something_like_that I guessed the same but now i am trying to guess is that stream getting feed by the time or just an iterator from a predefined Vec<String> but maybe i can guess the 2nd one because op wants to make optimization ? But is it ?

Comment: @ÖmerErden I'm sorry, updated the question to include `futures`. The stream getting feed by the time, it's correct.

Comment: `stream.fold(RepeatedField::new(), |mut r, item| future::ok(r.push(item))).into_future().and_then(|repeated_fields|{ /*use in here*/});` might help, also you need to spawn this future into executor to run async.

Comment: Please review how to create a [MCVE] and then [edit] your question to include it. Your code is **not syntactically valid** and we cannot tell what crates, types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. Try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) or in a brand new Cargo project. There are [Rust-specific MCVE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here.

Answer (score 1):

there are relevant pieces of code from protobuf sources:

```rust
/// Wrapper around vector to avoid deallocations on clear.
pub struct RepeatedField<T> {
    vec: Vec<T>,
    len: usize,
}

/// Create a contained with data from given vec.
#[inline]
pub fn from_vec(vec: Vec<T>) -> RepeatedField<T> {
    let len = vec.len();
    RepeatedField { vec: vec, len: len }
}
```

So no, your code is already easy and optimal: it creates the vector and then just moves it to the structure without unnecessary copying.